# Careers Site: "Don't forget! You can invite 0 colleagues to create their own Careers 2.0 profiles." notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, notification-bar

Just got the message going into the careers site:

> Don't forget! You can invite **0** colleagues to create their own Careers 2.0 profiles.

I still have 5 invites remaining according to the profile invitations page.

Was this message right?

Comment: If this isn't resolved after clearing your cache and refreshing the page, it's likely a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thanks for the report.  These messages are denormalized, and we were accidentally notifying people on zero invites for a little while and you got one of them.  Should be all fixed now.

Comment: this works for me, because I have 0 colleagues.